# Remove static int counter from this recursive solution

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I have this recursive code for counting the number of permutations a string can have

```
public class Permutation {

static int counter = 0;

public static int perms(String s, int level,int length) {

    if(level == length-1) {
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            String newString = s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 1);
            perms(newString,level + 1, length);
        }
    }
    return counter;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(perms("plot", 0, 4));

}
```

}

I was wondering how I can rewrite it so that it doesn't use `static int counter = 0`? Thanks!

NOTE: Yes, I know I can just use the permutation formula for this haha

Comment: would passing the counter into ```perms``` as an input work (since it's no longer a static int)? or are you trying to get rid of a counter altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the need for a static counter or passing a counter value to each method call. Note that your implementation counts all permutations and not unique permutations (String "aab" returns 6, not 3).

---

```java
public static int permsRedone(String s, int level,int length){
  int count = 0;

  if(level == length-1){
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      String newString = s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(i+1);
      count += permsRedone(newString,level+1,length);
    }
  }
  return count;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the counter as the fourth argument (using 0 as the initial value). Return it from perms and set it to the value returned from the inner call.

```
public static int perms2(String s, int level,int length, int count){
        if(level == length-1){
            count++;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                String newString = s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(i+1);
                count = perms2(newString,level+1,length, count);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```